# Why adjoint operator is not a generalization of transpose matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

I know in finite Hilbert spaces, the adjoint operator is a sort of generalization of the transpose matrix, in the sense that if $M$ is symmetric, then $\langle Mx,y\rangle=\langle x,My\rangle$. So if $M$ is not symmetric, we define the adjoint $M^*$ as $\langle Mx,y\rangle=\langle x,M^*y\rangle$. So it's a sort of generalization of transpose matrix (it's the way we justify it in the lecture). But the assistant says that it's a good point of view in finite dimension, but it doesn't work in finite dimension (despite if its self adjoint), and I don't understand why. His explanation was to be careful with the domain, but I still don't understand.

Comment: Maybe try considering $M:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. That way you can see that adjoints are also defined even when matrices are not square.

Comment: I thought the adjoint was a generalization of the conjugate transpose of a matrix.

Comment: I think you're trying to say that the adjoint operator is a generalization of **the transpose** of a matrix

Comment: I think that your assistant's misgiving is that in the context of unbounded linear operators, [self-adjoint and symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator) have distinct technical meanings.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Yes sorry, I was indeed thinking about transpose matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, over *complex* Hilbert spaces, the adjoint is indeed the analogue of the *conjugate* transpose.  (Consider the adjoint of scalar multiplication by $i$.)  EDIT:  Looking at the edit history, I guess you were disagreeing not with the 'conjugate' part, but with @‍user657324's use of 'symmetric' in place of 'transpose'.